# Proving Gale-Shapley algorithm completes in $O(n^2)$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, proof-explanation

In *Algorithm Design* by John Kleinberg and Eva Tardos, the proof for the [Gale-Shapley algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) running in $O(n^2)$ is given

> In the case of the present algorithm, each iteration consists of some man
>   proposing (for the only time) to a woman he has never proposed to
>   before. So if we let P(t) denote the set of pairs (m, w) such that m
>   has proposed to w by the end of iteration t, we see that for all t,
>   the size of P(t + 1) is strictly greater than the size of P(t). But
>   there are only $n^2$ possible pairs of men and women in total, so the
>   value of P(.) can increase at most $n^2$ times over the course of the
>   algorithm. It follows that there can be at most $n^2$ iterations.

Few questions:

1. What are we actually proving? I find it strange we are proving the running time is $O(n^2)$ because that's something we usually don't actually *prove*.
2. What does $.$ mean in $P(.)$?
3. I never actually defined what $n$ is but I'm assuming it's the number of men i.e. $|M|$?
4. I don't accept the statement "we see that for all t, the size of P(t + 1) is strictly greater than the size of P(t)" because if $m$ purposes to $w$ and $w$ was engaged to $m'$ but leaves $m'$ for $m$, then there the number of pairs hasn't gone up. Strictly greater than means it can't be equal (ie no change), right?
5. Isn't this proof just saying "since there are $n \times n$ ways to match elements from one set of size $n$ to another set of size $n$, the running time is at most $O(n^2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What are we actually proving? I find it strange we are proving the running time is $O(n^2)$ because that's something we usually don't actually *prove*.

What is it that you usually do?

2. What does $.$ mean in $P(.)$?

Anything, basically any value of $t$.  The $.$ is a common placeholder for a variable that you don't want to name.

3. I never actually defined what $n$ is but I'm assuming it's the number of men i.e. $|M|$?

Yes.

4. I don't accept the statement "we see that for all t, the size of P(t + 1) is strictly greater than the size of P(t)" because if $m$ purposes to $w$ and $w$ was engaged to $m'$ but leaves $m'$ for $m$, then there the number of pairs hasn't gone up. Strictly greater than means it can't be equal (ie no change), right?

$P(t)$ is the number of proposals made by time $t$, not proposals accepted.  If no new proposals are made, then the algorithm is finished.

5. Isn't this proof just saying "since there are $n \times n$ ways to match elements from one set of size $n$ to another set of size $n$, the running time is at most $O(n^2)$

There are $n!$ ways to match elements from one set of size $n$ to another set of size $n$.  There are $n^2$ ways of matching one element of a set of size $n$ to an element of another set of size $n$.

Comment: RE: #1 I guess I find it overly rigorous to call something a proof when determining the running time. For example quicksort has a running time of $O(n^2)$ but I don't usually see a formal proof of it e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Worst-case_analysis